# How to invert list used for a tikz foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Given

```
\def\stuff{a,b,c}
```

I would like to be able to do

```
\foreach \x in {c,b,a} {...}
```

without inverting the list `\stuff` manually.
For example is there some sort of `\invert` macro that would allow me to write

```
\foreach \x in \invert{\stuff} {...}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A manual solution, where the reversed list is constructed in a first `\foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\let\mylist\empty
\foreach\x in {1,...,4} {
  \ifx\mylist\empty
    \xdef\mylist{\x}%
  \else
    \xdef\mylist{\x,\mylist}%
  \fi
}
\foreach\x in \mylist {
  [\x]
}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 8):

You can use `xparse` to get a good way to feed `\foreach` with a control sequence holding the list and also to reverse it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Foreach}{ s m m m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \equaeghe_reverseforeach:Non #2 { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \equaeghe_foreach:Non #2 { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \equaeghe_foreach:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \foreach #1 in { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \equaeghe_reverseforeach:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__equaeghe_list_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_reverse:N \l__equaeghe_list_seq
  \tl_set:Nx \l__equaeghe_reverselist_tl
   { \seq_use:Nnnn \l__equaeghe_list_seq { , } { , } { , } }
  \equaeghe_foreach:NVn #1 \l__equaeghe_reverselist_tl { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \equaeghe_reverseforeach:Nnn { No }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \equaeghe_foreach:Nnn { NV } 
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \equaeghe_foreach:Nnn { No }

\tl_new:N \l__equaeghe_reverselist_tl
\seq_new:N \l__equaeghe_list_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\Foreach\x{a,b,c}{\x}

\Foreach*\x{a,b,c}{\x}

\Foreach\x{a,...,g}{\x}

\Foreach*\x{a,...,g}{\x}

\def\stuff{a,b,c}

\Foreach\x{\stuff}{\x}

\Foreach*\x{\stuff}{\x}

\end{document}
```

The *-version reverses the list.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach. I assume your list is a macro; it doesn't have to be. The `\foreach` loop gives you the transformed list

```
\mytranslist -> \do{4}\do{3}\do{2}\do{1}
```

You can then define `\do` to be any operator/processor that you wish. For example, to print the list, I define `\do` to yield the format `[x]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}    
\def\mylist{1,...,4}
\def\do#1{%
  \xdef\mytranslist{\noexpand\do{#1}%
    \ifdefined\mytranslist\unexpanded\expandafter{\mytranslist}\fi
  }%
}
\let\mytranslist\undefined
\foreach \x in \mylist {\do{\x}}
% To print the list:
\def\do#1{[#1]}
\mytranslist
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the latest version of *loops* package, you need less estate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{loops}[2012/10/10]
\begin{document}
\def\mylist{1,...,4}
\foreachfox [list is a macro, reverse list] \mylist {[#1]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where we can find `loops.sty`? Has it made to CTAN already?

Comment: I haven't seen it announced on `comp.text.tex`, the usual notice board used by CTAN. You may have to wait a few hours or days.